# Why is Svelte for VSCode so slow?

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

I'm working on a Svelte project and one of the page is quite big (around 2000 lines of code). I know it's too much but It's fine for what I want to do. Anyway, I'm just wondering why my editor takes so much time to autocomplete, or analyse the page.

Look at this [video showing how slow VSCode is](https://www.veed.io/view/896382fa-f467-41fb-99f1-52fba28e2617?panel=share) where I just typed a few lines and started recording.

When I look at the running extensions of VSCode, Svelte for VS Code takes 100ms for activation (which is the highest amount compared to the others). I don't have a lot of other extensions running at the same time.

Svelte for VS Code is the only one I have troubles with, and it works perfectly fine on small pages.

My computer can run games... but not VS Code? Can I "improve the performances" of VS Code ?

Comment: Actually There is no way to improve. You may try other IDE from JetBrains. Or Try in Other better device. VSCode is slow because It was built on top of Electron which would won `The World's Best RAM Eater` :-;

Comment: @AjayRaja disagreed. if you're observing slowness, it's not as deeply inherent to VS Code being built on electron as you think. More likely is that the slowness is inherent or due to a limitation or bug or in a technology-based extension or underlying tooling. Ex. the cpptools extension can be slow. But that's because C++ is a hard language in general to provide IntelliSense for. TypeScript IntelliSense in VS Code is quite snappy, and that's largely due to the underlying tsserver and TypeScript tooling. Or it's due to project scale or an environment-specific issue (Ex. antivirus)

Comment: speaking of antivirus, Thomas, do you have any antivirus enabled on your machine?

Comment: @user nope, I'm on a Macbook Air M1